# Problem with Largest Product in a Grid Algorithm PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I have tried to complete [Euler project problem 11](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11) but somehow I got a product that was actually above the right answer. I have tried to calculate the adjacent numbers through the use of a single dimensional array and nested for loops. What error in my code is making this occur?

Code:

````
$numbers = str_replace(" ","",$numbers);
$numbers = str_split($numbers, 2);

function removeZeros($numbers) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
        $firstChar = substr($numbers[$i], 0, 1);
        if ($firstChar == "0") {
            $numbers[$i] = substr($numbers[$i], 1, 1);
        }
    }
    return $numbers;
}

function gridProduct($numbers) {
    removeZeros($numbers);
    $i = 0;
    $product = 0;
    $largestGrid = 0;
    // across
    for ($j = 0; $j < 20; $j++) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 17; $i++) {
            $k = $i + ($j * 20);
            $product = $numbers[$k] * $numbers[$k + 1] * $numbers[$k + 2] * $numbers[$k + 3];
            if ($product > $largestGrid) {
                $largestGrid = $product;
            }
        }
    }
    // vertically
    for ($j = 0; $j < 20; $j++) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 17; $i++) {
            $k = $j + ($i * 20);
            $product = $numbers[$k] * $numbers[$k + 20] * $numbers[$k + 40] * $numbers[$k + 60];
            if ($product > $largestGrid) {
                $largestGrid = $product;
            }
        }
    }
    // diagonally right
    for ($j = 0; $j < 17; $j++) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 17; $i++) {
            $k = $i + ($j * 20);
            $product = $numbers[$k] * $numbers[$k + 21] * $numbers[$k + 21] * $numbers[$k + 21];
            if ($product > $largestGrid) {
                $largestGrid = $product;
            }
        }
    }
    // diagonally left
    for ($j = 19; $j > 4; $j--) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 17; $i++) {
            $k = $i + ($j * 20);
            $product = $numbers[$k] * $numbers[$k - 19] * $numbers[$k - 19] * $numbers[$k - 19];
            if ($product > $largestGrid) {
                $largestGrid = $product;
            }
        }
    }
    echo " ";
    echo $largestGrid;
}

gridProduct($numbers);```
````

Comment: After you `removeZeros`, the resulting matrix has no resemblance to the original one. The diagonals are messed up badly. No surprise the result is wrong.